# jquery to remove all z-index elements of a certain value

Tags: jquery, z-index

I'm trying to use jquery to remove all z-index values within a given selector that match a specific z-index.    Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use `.filter()` with a function that calls `.css("z-index")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the filter function:

```
$("yourselector").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("z-index") == 30; //change to your criteria
    //  OR
    //  return this.style.zIndex == 30;
}).css("z-index", ''); //your new zindex
```

Comment: OP stated "remove" the element, not "change"

Comment: @Joren this doesn't "change" anything. `.filter` is perfect for what OP wants

Comment: @Joren -- Then set it to 0, simple.

Comment: @SpYk3HH The bit at the very end does change it... `.css("z-index", 45);`

Comment: @tymeJV that way you will change the z-inde xto zero, not remove the entire element

Comment: @Joren Reread the question - `I'm trying to use jquery to remove all z-index *values*`

Comment: I just changed it to 0, the point of the answer was that the OP could customize it. Hence the "change to your criteria"

Comment: AdamJones wants the property removed. Not changed, not set to zero, but removed. There are special implications to this; [**see my answer.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19012317/2038227)

Comment: @theftprevention -- Values are different that properties. I don't see where it says the property should be removed.

Comment: Also, you'll find in some browser `this.style.zIndex` works better than `$(this).css("zIndex")`

Comment: Setting a css value to `''` does remove it from the element's style

Comment: @tymeJV - I misworded that first comment. Regardless, the question asked for a way to "remove all z-index values". It's not the distinction between "values" vs. "properties" that's important; it's "change" vs. "remove". Obviously, jQuery can't control the CSS of an element beyond changing its `style` attribute or dynamically loading a new stylesheet. So, to "remove the value", in this context, would mean to unset the z-index value in the `style` attribute (set it to a blank string), reverting that value back to whatever the stylesheet deems it should be.

Comment: @theftprevention thus the `'zIndex', ''` ... geez, ur arguing semantics at this point. Doesn't our Government do enough of that for us?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback.  I tried this on a specific selector and it worked fine.  I then tried on "body" 

$("body").filter(function() { ...

and it didn't work.  Why would that be?

Comment: @AdamJones -- Because there is only 1 body, and it will only check that `zIndex`

Comment: @AdamJones -- If you want to check all elements, you can use the `*` wildcard, `$("*").filter...`

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
var search = "2"; // Could also be "inherit", etc.
$('.selector').css('z-index', function(i, val) {
    return (val.toString() == search) ? '' : val;
});
```

[**See this demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qpjAJ/1/)

This way, if the `z-index` of the element isn't 2, then it's left alone. If it *is* 2, then it will be removed; in jQuery, **setting a CSS value to a blank string removes the value and defers it to the stylesheets in place.**

If you want to *change* the z-index rather than removing it, simply replace the blank string `''` with a new value or variable.

<sub>**Edit* for my own sanity: Did away with `parseInt()` in favor of converting the returned z-index to a string (jQuery tries to return an integer); this way we can accommodate searches for values such as `inherit`.</sub>

Comment: Don't forget the radix argument to parseInt.

Comment: Almost good answer, except there is still problems in some browsers (for instance my chrome) with reading `z-index` via jQuery. Thus this doesn't work cross-browser. I know because i just tested this and it's not working in my Chrome, but it does work in my FF. Which is shocking because the new FF is a fail browser in my opinion

Comment: @SpYk3HH - Was there an issue with your test? Check out [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qpjAJ/1/) and see if it works for you.

Comment: hmm, oddly enough, upon its base use as you have it yes. but when i change the `.text` in your base function to `console.log` all i get on the console is `undefined`. seems rather odd it show in the iFrame, but console logs as undefined. However, i'm able to console log any other "style" just fine. Sorry, console log is usually my go to for testing. Didn't actually make in browser test. seems it is getting a value. but console logging z-index doesn't work. while it does work for other style values. Must be an issue with chromes console engine

Comment: @SpYk3HH - That's odd... are you just doing `console.log(z);` within the `reportZ()` function? I just did that, and it works. Maybe you're not using the latest version of Chrome...?

Comment: I'm on a beta version but i'm about to go clean version. I've found a few issues with the new beta i'm not liking

Comment: Ah. Maybe this is one of them!